How to create a separate (data-only) subpackage
I have a main Python package, foo, and want to have a number of separately maintained subpackages foo.bar etc. The subpackages only contain data, i.e. yaml files, which are located in the root of my (git) repository. What needs to be in the pyproject.toml to achieve this? My minimal start was
[project]
name = "foo.bar"
description = "Bar data for foo"
dynamic = ["version"]
dependencies = ["foo"]

however, I now don't know how to add the package data, and to dynamically (from git-describe) add the version number. Also, which build system (if any) should one use?
